# Лучший способ расширения модели пользователя django

Tags: python, django

Хочу добавить аватар к модели пользователя. Попробовала добавить

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    avatar = models.ImageField(height_field=None, width_field=None, blank=True, upload_to="avatars/", default="avatars/default.jpg")`
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email')

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
        return cd['password2']

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Profile
        fields = ('avatar',)
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
       profile_form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)

    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
        new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])

        new_user.save()
        new_user.refresh_from_db()

        new_profile = Profile.objects.create(user=new_user, avatar=request.FILES['avatar'])
        new_profile.save()

        return render(request, 'accounts/reg.html', {
            'new_user': new_user,
            'new_profile': new_profile
        })
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        new_profile = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/reg.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'new_profile': new_profile
    })
```

**signals.py**

```
User = get_user_model()

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.profile = Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

Форма отрисовывется, но после сабмита получаю UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_profile.user_id. Всё смигрировала. В чём может быть дело, и как всё сделать лучше? Спасибо всем заранее)

Comment: Очевидно, вы пытаетесь создать второй профиль, хотя уже существует первый

Comment: Последняя строчка в post_save - лишняя

Comment: Большое спасибо всем! Я закомментила сигнал, но ошибка оставалась. Потом стёрла миграции из этого приложения и создала заново. Вот теперь всё отлично)

Comment: Иногда нужно перезагрузить сервер, чтобы ошибка ушла